# I want to Print each sentense in Next line in Center as Peom I have tried /n ,/r/n but I failed

Tags: javascript

```
<center><p id="demo" style="color:black;"></p></center>

<script>

window.onload = function() {
  typeWriter();
};
var i =0;
var txt = "Would it be ok if I wrote you a rhyme? would it be ok if I opened my heart? Would it be ok if I took on the part Of being your man and showed you a view, One that only a real man could do? Would it be ok if I could make you smile? Would it be alright to look in your eyes? Would it be alright to never tell lies? Would it be alright to find a way? Would it be alright to long for the day To pull you close and whisper in your ear And tell you our feelings are nothing to fear? Would it be ok if I took some of your time? Would it be ok if I wrote you a rhyme? To tell you there is nothing I would rather do Than spend my whole life loving only you... ";
var txt1= '';
var speed = 100;
function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt1.charAt(i);

    i++;
      setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);

  }

}
</script>
```

I want to Print every sentence in next line as a Poem...! But I can't Do it Please if There is Anybody who is willing to help .! I will Appreciate Him/Her
Thanks In Advance

Comment: I d suggest you take a look at String.prototype.split() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: Also you can use `<br>` tag to break text on different lines

Comment: Cant you give me Exact code of What I am Saying Bro ?

Answer (score 1):

Use your own flag for example char "#" .
I use simple check for char at index and use tag br/ . 
Better solution use char "?" for new line . See in code snippet example2 .

```html
<center><p id="demo" style="color:black;"></p></center>

<script>

window.onload = function() {
  typeWriter();
};
var i =0;
var txt = "Would it be ok if I wrote you a rhyme?# would it be ok if I opened my heart? # Would it be ok if I took on the part Of being your man and showed you a view, One that only a real man could do?# Would it be ok if I could make you smile?# Would it be alright to look in your eyes? Would it be alright to never tell lies?# Would it be alright to find a way?# Would it be alright to long for the day To pull you close and whisper in your ear And tell you our feelings are nothing to fear? Would it be ok if I took some of your time?# Would it be ok if I wrote you a rhyme?# To tell you there is nothing I would rather do Than spend my whole life loving only you... ";
var txt1= '';
var speed = 100;
function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    
    if (txt.charAt(i) == "#"){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<br/>";
    }
    else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
     }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt1.charAt(i);

    i++;
      setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);

  }

}
</script>
```

Example 2 :

```html
<center><p id="demo" style="color:black;"></p></center>

<script>

window.onload = function() {
  typeWriter();
};
var i =0;
var txt = "Would it be ok if I wrote you a rhyme? would it be ok if I opened my heart?  Would it be ok if I took on the part Of being your man and showed you a view, One that only a real man could do? Would it be ok if I could make you smile? Would it be alright to look in your eyes? Would it be alright to never tell lies?Would it be alright to find a way? Would it be alright to long for the day To pull you close and whisper in your ear And tell you our feelings are nothing to fear? Would it be ok if I took some of your time? Would it be ok if I wrote you a rhyme? To tell you there is nothing I would rather do Than spend my whole life loving only you... ";
var txt1= '';
var speed = 100;
function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    
    if (txt.charAt(i) == "?"){
    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<br/>";
   
    }
    else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
     }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt1.charAt(i);

    i++;
      setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);

  }

}
</script>
```

Example with bold ( little parser ) :
It is little complicated . We need dynamic creation element with append method also one FLAG .

```html
<center><p id="demo" style="color:black;"></p></center>

<script>

window.onload = function() {
  typeWriter();
};
var i =0;
var txt = "Would it be ok if I wrote you a #rhyme#? would it be ok if I opened my #heart#?  Would it be ok if I took on the part Of being your man and showed you a view, One that only a real man could do? Would it be ok if I could make you smile? Would it be alright to look in your eyes? Would it be alright to never tell lies?Would it be alright to find a way? Would it be alright to long for the day To pull you close and whisper in your ear And tell you our feelings are nothing to fear? Would it be ok if I took some of your time? Would it be ok if I wrote you a rhyme? To tell you there is nothing I would rather do Than spend my whole life loving only you... ";
var txt1= '';
var speed = 100;

var BOLD_ELE = null;
var isBold = false;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
  
     if (isBold == true ){
     
     var BOLD_ELE = document.createElement('B');
     document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(BOLD_ELE);
     
     }
    
    if (txt.charAt(i) == "?"){
    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<br/>";
   
    }
    else if (txt.charAt(i) == "#"){
       if (isBold == false) {
        isBold = true
       }
       else {
        isBold = false
       }
    
    }
    else {
    
    if (isBold == false){ 
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    }
    else {
     BOLD_ELE.innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    }
    
    }
    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt1.charAt(i);

    i++;
      setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);

  }

}
</script>
```

Comment: How will I bold The Text In it ?
Thanks in Advance